# Why do exponentiated values differ when the un-exponentiated regression coefficients of opposite sign are the same absolute value?

Tags: regression

I need to reverse the direction of effects for a series of binary logistic regressions. In theory, I should be able to change the sign, because the magnitude of the effect shouldn't be any different whether it is positive or negative.

To test that, I reverse coded my outcome variable and re-ran a series of regressions. Sure enough, the absolute values were identical, but opposite in sign. However, when I exponentiate the coefficients, the percent change in outcome for a 1 unit increase in predictor is quite different in size. Why do the exponentiated coefficients differ in magnitude when the un-exponentiated coefficients are identical in absolute value?

A specific example:
**original outcome beta**: -0.646, exponentiated to 0.524, thus 47.59% decrease in Y per 1 unit increase in X (1 - exponentiated coefficient, expressed as %);
**reverse coded outcome beta**: 0.646, exponentiated to 1.908, thus 90.79% increase in Y per 1 unit increase in X (exponentiated coefficient - 1, expressed as %)

Why does the negative effect show a ~47% decrease, but the positive shows a ~90% increase?

Comment: Exp is a non linear and monotonic transform so this is expected behaviour. Did you expect the odds ratios to be identical as well?

Comment: Agree with Demetri about the nonlinearity. Your question falls in the ubiquitous class of questions about relative or proportional changes with sign reversals, e.g., why is the % change from 110 to 120 units (9% change) not equivalent (with sign reversal) to the % change from 120 to 110 units (-8%)?

Comment: Thanks Mike for connection to returns. Ted: notice that $log(120) - log(110) = -(log(110) - log(120)$ so taking logs,  the inverse of exponentiating, removes the problem you experience. of course, don't do it but I was just pointing out the odd behavior of exponentiating.

Comment: @mlofton Actually, using logs doesn't *remove* the problem, it only mitigates it as post-hoc exponentiation will confirm.

Comment: This is extremely useful. I was assuming the difference in % change here had something to do with multiplicative effects, though I'm not savvy enough with the technical aspects of transformation to be sure what I had done was in fact correct. Thank you all for your clarifications and explanations about this!

Comment: Mike I was referring to your example with the 120 and the 110. I'm not sure what you are referring to. log(120) - log(110) is the exact negative of log(110) - log(120). that's all I was trying to show.

Comment: oh, and for small differences between the numbers, the result of the log difference will be very close to your percentage change calculation. I should have mentioned that. For larger percent changes, the approximation using the log gets worse and worse.